# Limitation of filters aggregation amount

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to use filters aggregation. Let's assume that my request looks like following:

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "messages": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "word1": {
            "match": {
              "body": "word1"
            }
          },
          "word2": {
            "match": {
              "body": "word2"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this case I mentioned 2 aggregations. How many filters aggregation can I use? 5, 10, 100, 500? Is it some limitation?

Thanks a lot for the answers!

Comment: I don't think there is a limit per say. But you might want to consider other way to filter then, like using `terms`

Comment: @Paulo, thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately,  this is the business logic. I will receive the input from the user for each filter aggregation and I want to know if I should limit the user with number of aggregation or not

Comment: Well then it depends on your use case, no one can really know. it depends on how big your cluster is, how much data you have.